# Jquery Title hover not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

EDIT: The issue appears to be the chosen plugin. Once I disable it, the tooltips are working fine. So the problem lies somewhere within that plugin I guess..

```
 var i = 0;
        $(".dropdown-toggle").children().each(function () {
            $(this).attr("title", serializedResult[i]);
            //$(this).tooltip();
            i++;
        });
```

The title attributes get added, but hover not working. Appereantly because when adding html dynamically, the functionality doesn't get updated. So I tried using .tooltip() from bootstrap, the title attribute gets changed again, but the hover, again, isn't working.

How can I make it so it displays what I want on hover, similar to adding a title before loading the page?

Edit:

So I'm working in MVC, this is my view:

```
<div class="col-md-3 red">
@using (Html.BeginForm("SelectGroup", "Werkvorm"))
{

    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.selectedItem, new SelectList(ViewBag.groepen, "id", "Naam"), "", 
    new { @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle chosen-select", data_placeholder = "Selecteer een groep-" })
    <input type="submit" id="zoekgroep" value="Zoeken" class="btn btn-primary" />

}
</div>
```

[image: https://s23.postimg.org/dxj7v91y3/my_view.png]

Html looks like this after page load:

```
<select class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle chosen-select" data-placeholder="Selecteer een groep-" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field selectedItem must be a number." data-val-required="Het veld selectedItem is vereist." id="selectedItem" name="selectedItem" style="display: none;"><option value="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Beschrijving groep1"></option>
<option value="1" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Beschrijving groep2">groep1</option>
<option value="2" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Beschrijving groep3">groep2</option>
<option value="3" data-toggle="tooltip">groep3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: In Bootstrap you need to add `data-toggle="tooltip"` as attribute to the element. http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp

Comment: $(".dropdown-toggle").children().each(function () {
            $(this).attr("data-toggle","tooltip");
            $(this).attr("title",serializedResult[i]);
            $(this).tooltip();
            i++;
        });


Doesn't work either.

Comment: *"Appereantly because when adding html dynamically, the functionality doesn't get updated."* - of course it does. Your problem is layers and stacking contexts. But it's impossible to help without actual demo of the problem.

Comment: @dfsq Updated my question to give more info.

Comment: Can you show us where you are invoking bootstrap's tool tip function? You tried invoking it after changing title?